# Image rotation with PDFBox

Tags: image, rotation, pdfbox

I am quit new to using PDFBox. What I need is to add an image with rotation to an exiting PDF! I know how to add the image, but my problem is how to rotate the image! I've seen somethign about AffineTransform and Matrix but I have no idea what is that and how it works!

I'd really appreciate passing some sample code, and thank you in advance!

Best Regards

Answer (score 5):

It helps to look at the source of the "simple" image display method:

```java
 public void drawXObject(PDXObject xobject, float x, float y, float width, float height)
 {
     AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform(width, 0, 0, height, x, y);
     drawXObject(xobject, transform);
 }
```

so this is what you do to display an image at (200,200) with a rotation of 45°:

```java
 AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(ximage.getWidth(), 0, 0, ximage.getHeight(), 200, 200);
 at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
 contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, at);
```

Re: AffineTransform: this is a subtopic of geometry. To get an introduction, read the java description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html).