# Why is apache pdfbox ImageUtil.getRotatedImage method increasing the size of buffered image?

Tags: pdfbox

I am using **getRotatedImage** function of **ImageUtil** class of **apache** **pdfbox** library to rotate a Buffered Image. The output is perfectly rotated image provided with Buffered image and degree of rotation. The only problem is that the output image when converted to pdf is more than double the size of original image, i.e 1.7MB image is converted to 4.3MB pdf.
Is there any problem with *ImageUtil.getRotatedImage* method of pdfbox library.

The format of image was .tif and i used *LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bim)* to create PDImageXObject object.

Comment: What was the format of the source image? What method did you use to create the image XObject?

Comment: The format of image was .tif and i used *LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, bim)* to create PDImageXObject object.

Comment: Was it a black and white tif? Then you're likely losing the excellent G4 compression and getting Flate compression instead. Try `CCITTFactory`. For rotation, rotate / translate the CTM. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867451/image-rotation-with-pdfbox

Comment: Btw, the ImageUtil class is from PDFDebugger. That isn't part of the API, it's just something to help with display.